# How to override delete of jQuery calendar so that i can also delete my database data

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using jquery calendar to show some information.So on click of the events in the date i am am getting the delete pop up i wan to do a delete using that .How i can do it?? This is my calerdar code  which i am using here

```
 $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                            {

                            events:[
                                    {

                                title: val.title,
                                start: val.start,
                                end: val.end,

                            }
                       ],
```

The title is showing the event name and on click of that event i am geting delete pop up ,how i will use that to delete that event?? Please help

Comment: I wan to use a click on the event rendered in the calendar ,somebody please help

Comment: Is this the right approach please someone help ..i am trying but nothing happening

Comment: I am trying to implement a pop up on click of the event but it is showing a.start is undefined

Comment: somebody help me out with this issue

Answer (score 1):

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        // make a call to your server telling it to delete the event.
        var promise = $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: 'yourendpoint/' + calEvent.title
        });

        promise.then(function () {/* delete event from calendar */})
    }
});
```